# How to destroy an activity

Tags: java, android, android-activity, destroy

In fact, I am new to Android App Development. In my application, I have a couple of activities and I have provided my users with an exit option menu to be able to leave the application. But there is a problem. When they hit the Exit button, they are able to leave the application but when they enter the application for the second time, the page that they left off the last time will be launched.
Here comes my code:

```
@Override
public boolean onMenuItemSelected(int featureId, MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case 0 :
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
            intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
            intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            startActivity(intent);
            finish();
            Toast.makeText(this, "Goodbye Dear", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            break;
```

Comment: "I have provided my users with an exit option menu to be able to leave the application" -- please don't. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2033914/quitting-an-application-is-that-frowned-upon/2034238#2034238

Comment: better give an example with A and B activity

Comment: CommomnsWare already said it.  "Exit" is nearly always evil.

Answer (score 1):

Android Activity has two methods `onPause` and `onDestroy` where you can do the necessary cleanup.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html

Comment: This scarcely answers the question.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `finish()`, use `System.exit(0);`.

Comment: No, this is quite in conflict with the design of Android, and may well not achieve the desired goal, as it likely will not affect Android's idea of where a recreated process should start.

Answer (score 0):

You have to override onPause and/or onDestroy methods inside your activity and delete your view within these methods.

Comment: No, one does not normally delete views.  The issue here is with the flow between Activities.

Answer (score 0):

The problem in your code is that `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK` doesn't remove your current Task. Read more about it here: [Task and Back Stack | Android Developers](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/tasks-and-back-stack.html).

Try using `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP`. From the documentation we can see that this gives the desired behavior.

> If set, and the activity being launched is already running in the
>   current task, then instead of launching a new instance of that
>   activity, all of the other activities on top of it will be closed and
>   this Intent will be delivered to the (now on top) old activity as a
>   new Intent.